Failed to convert a list returned by tapply into a data.frame
I'm doing some data operation with tapply(), and it returns a list-like object. For example:
x <- 1:10
y <- rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 5)
lst.1 <- tapply(x, y, function(vec) return(vec), simplify = FALSE)
lst.1

# $A
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $B
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10

I want to transform it into a data.frame. An intuition is using as.data.frame(), but it failed.
as.data.frame(lst.1)

#             lst1
# A  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
# B 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

I create another list manually to mimic lst.1, and as.data.frame() works as expedted.
lst.2 <- list(A = 1:5, B = 6:10)
lst.2

# $A
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $B
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10

as.data.frame(lst.2)

#   A  B
# 1 1  6
# 2 2  7
# 3 3  8
# 4 4  9
# 5 5 10

What's the difference between lst.1 and lst.2? And how to correctly convert a list returned by tapply (i.e. lst.1) into a data.frame?

If you take a look at the structure of the list being returned by tapply(), you'll see that it has a dimension attribute and is a list and an array.
str(lst.1)
List of 2
 $ A: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ B: int [1:5] 6 7 8 9 10
 - attr(*, "dim")= int 2
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "A" "B"

is.array(lst.1)
[1] TRUE

This means when you call as.data.frame() the method being dispatched under the hood is as.data.frame.array() and not as.data.frame.list().  To get around this you can invoke the method you want to use directly:
as.data.frame.list(lst.1) 
  A  B
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10

Or use:
list2DF(lst.1)
  A  B
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10


Thanks for your solutions. as.data.frame.list and list2DF work perfectly. But in my example, even I set simplify = TRUE, as.data.frame still fails.

@user18894435 - oops, should have tested that before suggesting it.  Removed.

From ?tapply:

If FUN does not return a single atomic value, tapply returns "an array of mode list" whose components are the values of the individual calls to FUN, i.e., the result is "a list with a dim attribute".

Therefore, lst.1 is actually closer to an array, even though it looks like a list. The following table shows some differences in terms of their class, dim, and dimnames.




class()
dim()
dimnames()




lst.2
"list"
NULL
NULL


lst.1
"array"
2
[[1]]  [1] "A" "B"



Two solutions to convert lst.1 into a data.frame:

Explicitly call the as.data.frame method for class 'list':
as.data.frame.list(lst.1)


Use c() to untie the list-array as an ordinary list:
as.data.frame(c(lst.1))



Output
  A  B
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10


Thanks for your solutions. as.data.frame.list() and c() work perfectly.
